# Why doesn't the OP have last say on question edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I have a modest reputation on stack overflow. I just posted a question on the main site and someone edited it to add tags that really didn't apply. After something like 500 rep the OP should have final say on edits to his or her question. This way someone who does know how to ask a question doesn't have his or her question adversely changed by another user. Thoughts?

Comment: These sites are community maintained, anyone can edit your question to add tags, etc. if they feel that the edits are applicable.

Comment: Nobody has the final say.  Other then a moderator when he locks a question because he get's fed up with an edit war.  If you don't like your question edited then SE is not the right place to ask questions.

Comment: @bluefeet I understand that but I think I know what I wanna ask better than the random user

Comment: What on earth makes you think that people with 500 rep know how to ask a question! I'm crap at it (waffle too much) and most mods have a few closed... let people improve your question; they're only trying to help you get better answers, which should be the point.

Comment: Users with editing privileges are hardly random users.  They were given editing privileges because they've earned the community's trust.  For the most part, they do a pretty good job maintaining content at a reasonable level of quality.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I am not saying that my questions don't need editing lord knows they do. Just give me final say

Comment: If the question you mention is "Using alternate id for Model id" then I belive tereško *correctly* added those tags since in your question you mentioned both mongodb and canjs. If they weren't related then why did you even mention them in the question body? The next edit, suggest by Paul Mougel, is incorrect since it inserts a tag to something never mentioned before. However, *as you already experimented*, you can still re-edit the question so I don't see the point of this meta question.

Comment: You do have the final say; you can roll back an edit, or edit the question yourself. High-rep users *also* have the final say; they can do the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OP does have final say, even with 1 reputation point, but only for **suggested edits** aka edits made by users with less than 2000  reputation.

Two cases:

1. Single user with 2K reputation is considered veteran and responsible enough to make a full edit without any review.
2. Three users (only on Stack Overflow, two on all other sites) with 2K reputation can approve edit suggested by any <2K user as three sets of eyes and minds should rarely make a grave mistake.

All this said, mistakes do happen, you have full right to rollback the edit and you can also notify the editor via `@` comment reply of his mistake.

Comment: And the OP can always roll back.. Not that continuously rolling back as a good idea, but the option to at least undo an edit is there.

Comment: what can we do if OP selects 'reject and edit' a valid edit and instead of selecting "improve edit"? Is there anyway to get it approved?

Comment: @NogShine no, no such way as far as I know. The edit will have to be made by a 2k user or mod.